# Profile Synchronization Status don't work in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: active-directory, profile-sync, active-directory-import

Im using SP2013 and I tried to import data from AD to SP 2013, but I got problem when I start sync. The Profile Synchronization Status don't work, it still 'Idle'. Here is some images of my configuration.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Anything useful appearing in ULS? Are all the relevant SharePoint services running, i.e. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx#StartUPSSProc?

Comment: When I use AD Import. "User Profile Synchronization Service" must be stop. Because if I want to start this service, I need to change "Synchronization Option" to "Use SharePoint Profile Synchronization" not "Sharepoint Active Directory Import".

Comment: Ah, bad choice of service example, sorry. What does your synchronization connection look like? And does the configured account have Replicating Directory permissions?

Comment: are you doing ADI or User Profile Sync? if user Profile Sync, could you please check if FIM services are started from services console.

Comment: @user3622351 have you solved this issue???